Can the processor speculatively fetch instructions in MMIO space?
Why does it say in the instruction manual that speculative instruction fetching can be performed to a certain extent? What's the reason for it? Can the processor speculatively fetch instructions in MMIO space?
I think speculative instruction fetching from MMIO can have undesirable consequencesenter image description here

Instruction fetch speculative execution is described in 3.6.7. Idempotency PMAs of the RISC-V instruction manual.

What processor are you talking about and what "undesirable consequences" are you worried about? You may also want see if this question is already answered on https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour
